# Wordpress site not working after move

Tags: htaccess

My site used to be in www.website.com/wordpress, now I've moved it to the root (www.website.com).

I followed the wp codex instructions:
1. changed site url in admin cp - after I saved changes, I got an error message (probably because the site wasn't there yet)
2. moved all the files from /wordpress folder to root folder.
3. updated permalinks in the new admin cp (the site worked fine), made sure htaccess was writable.

Then suddenly, only admin panel works - not the pages. I'm not even sure I did anything before it stopped working...

What could be wrong?

Comment: I used the same htaccess file so it's probably not corrupted htaccess? Also, I tried adding memory with php.ini. I also tried disabling plugins and re-uploading core files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to login to the database and manually edit 2 entries. In the wp_options table you can find `siteurl` and `home`. Update those appropriately, you should then be able to login properly.

You also need to update your `.htaccess` file but if you edit your permalink options and then change them back this should rewrite it for you.

For future reference to simply change directory of your installation if you login to the WP admin and go to Admin -> Settings -> General you can change the Wordpress Address and Site Address (the options you changed manually in the database) there. Once changed simply copy the entire installation folder to the new location and that will be it. It's easier to make the changes before you move it than after.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, and this is what worked for me: go to Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks. Under Common Settings, select another URL structure, click Save Changes (for me it was changing from Day and name to Plain). Got to your website, and see that pages are working again with the changed URL structure. And then change it back to what you had before (for me it was changing from Plain to Day and name).